# TypeError: 'sinker' object is not callable - in for each loop - works if I change variable name

Tags: python, for-loop

There are 3 classes (sinker, bond, series) and a test script.  The test script works fine if I change the variable name sinker to xsinker in the for each loop.  It also "works" if I move the sinker=sinker() outside of the for each loop.  I would really like to understand the nuance of why xsinker = sinker() works but sinker = sinker() does not.  Thx.

*sinker.py*

```
class sinker():

    def __init__(self):
        self.sinkerID = ''
        self.maturity = ''
        self.amount = 0.0
```

*bond.py*

```
from sinker import sinker

class bond():

    def __init__(self):
        self.baseCusip = ''
        self.suffixCusip = ''
        self.yld = 0.000
        self.price = 100.000
        self.frequency = 2
        self.sinkers = []

    def addSinker(self, sinker):
        self.sinkers.append(sinker)

    def amount(self):
        return sum([sinker.amount for sinker in self.sinkers])

    def cusip(self):
        return self.baseCusip + self.suffixCusip

    def maturity(self):
        return max([sinker.maturity for sinker in self.sinkers])
```

*series.py*

```
from bond import bond

class series():

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ''
        self.deliveryDate = ''
        self.datedDate = ''
        self.firstCoupon = ''
        self.tax = ''
        self.obligor = ''
        self.bonds = []

    def addBond(self, bond):
        self.bonds.append(bond)

    def amount(self):
         return sum([bond.amount() for bond in self.bonds])
```

*testcsv.py*  -- this doesn't work

```
"""This script imports series, bond and sinker data from a csv file and prints it."""

import sys, csv
sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\a-itfeld\Google Drive\code\python\muniAnalytics\dataStructure')

from series import series
from bond import bond
from sinker import sinker

Data = csv.reader(open(r'C:\Users\a-itfeld\Google Drive\code\python\muniAnalytics\testScripts\Data.csv'), delimiter=',')

series = series()
bond = bond()

# series data
series.name = '2010FF'
series.deliveryDate = '11/3/2010'
series.datedDate = series.deliveryDate
series.firstCoupon = '15/6/2010'
series.tax = "Tax Exempt"
series.obligor = "NYW"

# bond data
bond.baseCusip = '647102F'
bond.suffixCusip = 'A0'

# add sinkers to bond
for r in Data:
    sinker = sinker()
    sinker.maturity, sinker.amount = r[0], float(r[1])
    sinker.sinkerID = bond.cusip() + sinker.maturity
    bond.addSinker(sinker)

# add bond to series
series.addBond(bond)

# print the bonds added to series
for b in series.bonds:
   print(b.cusip(), b.maturity(), b.amount())


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\a-itfeld\Google Drive\code\python\muniAnalytics\testScripts\testCsv.py", line 30, in <module>
    sinker = sinker()
TypeError: 'sinker' object is not callable
```

*testcsv.py version 2*  -- this works

```
"""This script imports series, bond and sinker data from a csv file and prints it."""

import sys, csv
sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\a-itfeld\Google Drive\code\python\muniAnalytics\dataStructure')

from series import series
from bond import bond
from sinker import sinker

Data = csv.reader(open(r'C:\Users\a-itfeld\Google Drive\code\python\muniAnalytics\testScripts\Data.csv'), delimiter=',')

series = series()
bond = bond()

# series data
series.name = '2010FF'
series.deliveryDate = '11/3/2010'
series.datedDate = series.deliveryDate
series.firstCoupon = '15/6/2010'
series.tax = "Tax Exempt"
series.obligor = "NYW"

# bond data
bond.baseCusip = '647102F'
bond.suffixCusip = 'A0'

# add sinkers to bond
for r in Data:
    xsinker = sinker()
    xsinker.maturity, xsinker.amount = r[0], float(r[1])
    xsinker.sinkerID = bond.cusip() + xsinker.maturity
    bond.addSinker(xsinker)

# add bond to series
series.addBond(bond)

# print the bonds added to series
for b in series.bonds:
    print(b.cusip(), b.maturity(), b.amount())



647102FA0 15/06/2015 8750.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course. You do

```
sinker = sinker()
```

in a for loop.

The first call works, but then `sinker` isn't bound to the function you call, but to the result of that first call. And that isn't callable.

Compare the following situations:

```
def sinker():
    return 42

xsinker = sinker()
xsinker = sinker()
xsinker = sinker()
xsinker = sinker()
# This one you can do as often as you want - sinker is untouched.
sinker = sinker()
# Now sinker isn't the function any longer, but is 42.
# That's why
sinker = sinker()
# fails: you cannot call 42.
```

Comment: However if you do xsinker=sinker() and use xsinker it works?  What is the difference?

Comment: @itayfeldman The difference is what `sinker` is at the end of the assignment process. If you assign the result to `xsinker`, `sinker` is untouched. If you assign it to `sinker`, the old meaning is lost.